# Show that $\left| \frac{\sin z}{z} \right|≤e^{|z|}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $\left| \frac{\sin z}{z} \right|≤e^{|z|}$, $z \neq 0$

I've tried to play around with the exponential form a bit but I'm stuck.

$$
\left| \frac{\sin z}{z} \right|= \left| \sin z \right| \frac{1}{\left| z \right|}=\left|\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} \right|\frac{1}{\left| z \right|} 
$$

Can I do something with this at all?

Comment: This is maybe easiest done using the Maclaurin series.

Comment: Okay

$$
\frac{sinz}{z}= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
$$

then what? Isn't this only going to hold for $z$ around 0?

Comment: That series converges on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Then triangle inequality.

Comment: Oh yeah, ofc it does! Could you push me a little further? Still don't really understand how to do this, triangle inequality you say?

Comment: Yes, throwing the triangle inequality at $$\Biggl\lvert\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\Biggr\rvert$$ produces what?

Comment: That would just throw the absolute value bars inside the summation right?

Comment: Yes. And knowing where you want to end up, can you see how to continue?

Comment: No I'm sorry if I am a bit too slow here but I get that the summation is less than
$$
\sum\limits_{n=o}^\infty \left| \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \right|
$$
but how to go from here? I'm thinking that this shouldn't be too hard now but I can't see it.

Comment: Or is it maybe enough to say this?
$$

\sum\limits_{n=o}^\infty \left| \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \right| ≤ \sum\limits_{n=o}^\infty \left| \frac{z^{n}}{n!} \right|

$$

Comment: It's not enough to just say it, but that is what you want to show. A hint: $(2n+1)! \geqslant (2n)!$.

Comment: Well
$$
\sum\limits_{n=o}^\infty \left| \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \right|≤\sum\limits_{n=o}^\infty \left| \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right| ≤
\sum\limits_{n=o}^\infty \left| \frac{z^{2n}}{n!} \right|
$$
But the last term is bigger than what I want to show?

Comment: The last inequality should be $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^{2n}}{(2n)!} \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^n}{n!}.$$ Why does that hold?

Comment: Ohhhh right, ofc! The denominator grows faster, I could show that with some test if I want to? I think my professor would buy that anyway since that's just single variable calculus.

Comment: $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^{2n}}{(2n)!} \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\lvert z\rvert^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Now you confused me again, haha...

Comment: On the right hand side, we added something non-negative, so it's not smaller than the left. And if you rearrange the right hand side, you get exactly $e^{\lvert z\rvert}$.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$${\sin z\over z}={1\over2}\int_{-1}^1e^{itz}\>dt\ .$$
Since ${\rm Re}(itz)\leq |z|$ when $-1\leq t\leq 1$ we immediately obtain
$$\left|{\sin z\over z}\right|\leq e^{|z|}\qquad(z\in{\mathbb C})\ .$$

Comment: That is elegant!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Assuming $z=a+bi$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\left|\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right| ≤ e^{|z|} \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\left|\sin(z)\right|}{\left|z\right|} ≤ e^{|z|} \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\left|\sin(a+bi)\right|}{\left|a+bi\right|} ≤ e^{|a+bi|} \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{\cosh(2b)-\cos(2a)}}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} ≤ e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{\cosh(2b)-\cos(2a)}}{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2}} ≤ e^{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$